# descending order Arraylist<hashmap>

Tags: android, android-studio

how to sort descending on Arraylist <hashmap <string, string>?
i don't know how to do it

**my code**
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list_data.size(); i++) {

        NSM = list_data.get(i).get("nama_sekolah");
        HashMap<String,String> unsortMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Nuang.set(i, minUang / Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Nuang.get(i))));
        NJsiswa.set(i, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NJsiswa.get(i))) / maxSiswa);
        NEks.set(i, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NEks.get(i))) / maxEks);
        NAk.set(i, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NAk.get(i))) / maxAk);
        NLes.set(i, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NLes.get(i))) / maxLes);
        NBs.set(i, Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NBs.get(i))) / maxBs);

        Double NNuang = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(Nuang.get(i)));
        Double NNJsiswa = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NJsiswa.get(i)));
        Double NNEks = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NEks.get(i)));
        Double NNAk = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NAk.get(i)));
        Double NNLes = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NLes.get(i)));
        Double NNBs = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(NBs.get(i)));

        Q1 = 0.5 * ((NNuang * BUs) + (NNJsiswa * BJs) + (NNEks * BEks) + (NNAk * BAk) + (NNLes * BLes) + (NNBs * BBs));
        Q2 = 0.5 * ((Math.pow(NNuang, BUs)) * (Math.pow(NNJsiswa, BJs)) * (Math.pow(NNEks, BEks)) * (Math.pow(NNAk, BAk)) * (Math.pow(NNLes, BLes)) * (Math.pow(NNBs, BBs)));
        unsortMap.put("nama_sekolah",NSM);
        unsortMap.put("nilai",String.valueOf(Q1+Q2));
        data.add(unsortMap);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterList(ViewList.this,data));

    }
```

Comment: Well it depends how you would compare two string-to-string maps? They don't have an obvious order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Details  {

public static void main(String args[]){
   ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
   arraylist.add("AA");
   arraylist.add("ZZ");
   arraylist.add("CC");
   arraylist.add("FF");

   /*Unsorted List: ArrayList content before sorting*/
   System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
   for(String str: arraylist){
        System.out.println(str);
    }

   /* Sorting in decreasing order*/
   Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());

   /* Sorted List in reverse order*/
   System.out.println("ArrayList in descending order:");
   for(String str: arraylist){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

}

I found this example here:  https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/sort-arraylist-in-descending-order-in-java/